# rsa algorithm in openmp

Tags: c, parallel-processing, rsa, openmp

I am trying to parallize RSA algorithm with the help of repeated square and multiply method in openmp.
code is as follow:

```
long long unsigned int mod_exp(int base,int exp,int n)
{
    long long unsigned int i,pow1=1,pow2=1,pow3=1,pow4=1,pow=1,pow5=1;
    int exp1=exp/4; 
    int id;

    for(i=0;i<exp1;i++)
        pow1=(pow1*base)%n;

    for(i=0;i<exp1;i++)
        pow2=(pow2*base)%n;

    for(i=0;i<exp1;i++)
        pow3=(pow3*base)%n;

    for(i=0;i<exp1;i++)
        pow4=(pow4*base)%n;

    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
        pow5=(pow5*base)%n;
    pow=pow1*pow2*pow3*pow4*pow5;

    pow=pow%n;
    return pow;
}
```

just with #pragma omp for i am unable to find get the correct output.
kindly help

Comment: *"i am unable to find get the correct output"* is not at all helpful. What do expect to get, what do you get and what are your inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could go for something like this:

```
long long unsigned int i, pow = 1, exp1 = exp / 4;
int k;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction( * : pow )
for ( k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
    for ( i = 0; i < exp1 ; i++ ) {
        pow = ( pow * base ) % n;
    }
}
```

That should work but I doubt it would do you much good since the amount of work is so limited that the parallelisation overhead is very likely to slow-down the code instead of speeding it up.

EDIT: hum, actually, I can't make sense of the initial code... Why are we doing 5 times the same computation? Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891372/parallel-execution-of-openmp-got-stuck-after-taking-some-input